# Simple form of mysqli result required

Tags: php, mysqli

I am mysqli upgrading from mysql. I know how to use basic connect and query statements. But I can't get the result statement to work. All the solutions on the net I have found blind me with science. I would like to have "mysql_result" working in mysqli.

```
$alltb = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$alltbd=mysqli_query($conned, $alltb);
$num_all=mysqli_num_rows($alltbd); 
mysqli_close($conned);
$i = 0;
while($i < $num_all){ 
    $ttt=mysql_result($alltbd,$i,"ttt"); 
    $sss=mysql_result($alltbd,$i,"sss");
    print $ttt . " and " . $sss;
$i++;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I don't want to use things like fetch, for each or array. I would like to keep it simple.

Garry Jones
Sweden

Answer (score 1):

You can do [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) for example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

$sqlResult = mysqli_query($conned, $query);

$allRecords = mysqli_fetch_all($sqlResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

mysqli_close($conned);

foreach($allRecords as $record) {
    $ttt = $record['ttt']; 
    $sss = $record['sss'];
    print $ttt . " and " . $sss;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I just wanted to run it on 5 values I would use while($i < 5) what is the eqiv of that?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 5`